# Software to track how many hours did I study subjects?

Tags: monitoring

I am studying

- operating systems
- bash shell scripting
- docker
- kubernetes
- regular expressions
- performance monitoring of linux servers
- security and hardening of linux servers

I want to track how long each takes me so that I can plan like that and make myself efficient.

I want a timer where I can put "operating systems", close the timer once I finish studying that subject for that day. And after a while, I should be able to see the graph of my study hours for a particular subject.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Quire](https://quire.io), a task management app. It has a timer as part of it's Professional paid plan. Quire is arguably the best task management app out there. The free version is very good... but it doesn't have the timer option.

Answer (score 0):

I made an app a while ago that may do exactly what you're looking for:

[Timekeeper](https://github.com/skauertz/Timekeeper)

Works on Linux and Windows.